# VsVim port keyboard settings to another VS instance

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard, vsvim

I am using VsVim in VS2015. I assign certain key combinations to be handled by VS or VsVim (see Tools -> Options -> VsVim -> Keyboard). I`m using VMs quite frequently with fresh installation of VS2015.

How can I port keyboard settings to that other VM without having to manually specify my desired keyboard bindings each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is an open feature-request on the VsVim project.

See [Issue #1921: Store vsvim settings in file](https://github.com/jaredpar/VsVim/issues/1921).